# Someone can help me the create a alarm android automatic?

Tags: android, automation, clock, alarm

I need create a code of notifications with alarm for android that meets the requirements:

- The APP must provide a selector of `STARTTIME` and a `ENDTIME` of your workday.(Because I need to calculate the difference between the hours for generate the `TOTALTIME`)
- The notification (the Alarm) should have a status of active or inactive.(For the alarm don't ringing without permission.)
- The notification (the Alarm) should continue working till when the cell phone is off equal to "Broadcast at the Eclipse or Android Studio"
- The notification (the Alarm) only should start of accord with the `STARTTIME` selected.

Now i need that it working with the following conditions when is active:

- The `ALARM1` variable should do a notification when achieve "<5% of variable `TOTALTIME`", after that the `TOTALTIME` achieve ">=5%" the variable `ALARM2` should get in loop, notifying me of 2 in 2 hours till the `TOTALTIME` achieve "97%" and for last, i need that the variable `ALARM3` show me a last notification when the `TOTALTIME` achieve  ">=97%".

Comment: So, what code have you tried so far....?

Comment: Do you expect the whole code for all that to be given as answer!

Comment: Haha, nice one. April Fool's to you too, @Technologia Grupo Posture!

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

---

### MainActivity.java

```
package br.exemploalarmmanagerbn;
import java.util.Calendar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        boolean alarmeAtivo = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent("ALARME_DISPARADO"), PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) == null);  
        if(alarmeAtivo){
            Log.i("Script", "Novo alarme");
            Intent intent = new Intent("ALARME_DISPARADO");
            PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
            c.add(Calendar.SECOND, 3);
            AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarme.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), 5000, p);
        }
        else{
            Log.i("Script", "Alarme já ativo");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        /*Intent intent = new Intent("ALARME_DISPARADO");
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarme.cancel(p);*/
    }
}
```

---

### BroadcastReceiverAux.java

```
package br.exemploalarmmanagerbn;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.Ringtone;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
public class BroadcastReceiverAux extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        Log.i("Script", "-> Alarme");
        gerarNotificacao(context, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), "Nova mensagem", "Título", "Descrição nova mensagem");
    }
    public void gerarNotificacao(Context context, Intent intent, CharSequence ticker, CharSequence titulo, CharSequence descricao){
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0); 
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        builder.setTicker(ticker);
        builder.setContentTitle(titulo);
        builder.setContentText(descricao);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        builder.setContentIntent(p);    
        Notification n = builder.build();
        n.vibrate = new long[]{150, 300, 150, 600};
        n.flags = Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        nm.notify(R.drawable.ic_launcher, n);
        try{
            Uri som = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            Ringtone toque = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, som);
            toque.play();
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

---

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Exemplo AlarmManager" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.exemploalarmmanagerbn"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="br.exemploalarmmanagerbn.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="BroadcastReceiverAux" android:label="BroadcastReceiverAux">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ALARME_DISPARADO"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Sorry me is my first time in a forum, still don't  know how 
act in him.

I got so far these codes. The problem are conditions of code, how do i do these conditions.